# ISO C++: How to design events?

Tags: c++, events, design-patterns, iso

I know 2 ways for desiging an event in C++:

## 1: Using callbacks:

```
typedef void (*callback_type)(void);

class my_class
{
  public:

    my_class(callback_type c)
    {
       m_callback = c;
    }

    void raise_event()
    {
       m_callback();
    }

  private:

    callback_type m_callback;
};
```

## 2: Using `virtual` methods:

```
class my_class
{
   public:

   virtual void my_event() = 0;

   void raise_event()
   {
      my_event();
   }
};

class main_class : public my_class
{
   public:

   virtual void my_event()
   {
      // Handle EVENT.
   }
};
```

Is there any other way or other idea for designing events?

and

**What is the best pattern for designing events in ISO C++?**

Comment: Note ISO C++ now refers to C++11.

Comment: ISO C++ is the standard for Language constructs and semantics not a book that specify's or suggests design patterns.

Comment: Each method in which asynchronous mechanisms can be implemented will have own advantages and disadvantages,You need to specify your requirements so as to be suggested the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Boost.Signals or Boost.Signals2.
To emulate those, you can use a collection of Boost.Function's/`std::function`'s.
To emulate those, you use type erasure (so the virtual function route) for flexibility.

Note that none of that is too trivial, so you should really try to use an existing solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The design will depend on the specifics of your requirements. For a nice example, see [ACE Reactor](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-rules.pdf).

Comment: Should this be an answer? because it looks,feels and sounds like a comment,Oh yes, it is an comment!

Comment: @Als: I don't see how this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @GMan: Because it does not help the OP solve the problem,not too hard that reason IMO.The Q is not clear enough to answer,then one should seek more information to answer it,not post not an answer as answer.